# Storyboard with Masonry

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder, autolayout, masonry-ios-osx

What's the good way of using Masonry with storyboard?
Currently I am adding views in interface builder, setting random constraints generated by XCode and then I remove them from runtime in IB as well as add them in code with Masonry.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the views to your storyboard without adding any constraints. Connect the views via outlets to your code and than add the constraints with Masonry.